# Can't to enable mpmstats log of Apache server

Tags: apache

I would like to config Apache server for mpmstat log which look like IBM HTTP server log as below

[Fri Jun 19 12:40:14.101123 2020] [mpmstats:notice] [pid 24510610:tid 1] mpmstats: rdy 149 bsy 1 rd 1 wr 0 ka 0 log 0 dns 0
cls 0

I don't know how to config it.

Could you help me to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable server-status page to check mpmstats in Apache httpd.i.e

```
<Location "/server-status">
    SetHandler server-status
    Require ip IP-address
</Location>
```

Refer https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_status.html for more information.

Comment: Thank you for youre anwser,

Can I write log mpmstats in log file ?

Comment: As far I know that there is no such functionality. You can use the script to capture this output in separate file.